# Indexing the columns of matrices in a list by another list

Tags: r

Suppose I have a list containing two matrices with different dimensions.

```
a <- matrix(rnorm(n=12), nrow = 3, ncol=4)
b <- matrix(rnorm(n=12), nrow = 4, ncol=3)
list1 <- list(a, b)

list1

#[[1]]
#           [,1]       [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
#[1,] -1.4654114  2.1251278 2.5363265 0.3127435
#[2,]  0.5701815 -1.0877491 0.6314599 1.5293045
#[3,]  2.0811299  0.3109243 0.2300760 0.5495488
#
#[[2]]
#          [,1]      [,2]     [,3]
#[1,] 0.9082071 1.7337076 2.207299
#[2,] 2.1287871 1.6839454 1.527546
#[3,] 0.8175804 0.8086223 1.165589
#[4,] 0.7410989 0.8237012 1.729501
```

Additionally, I have a list containing two vectors.

```
a2 <- c("yes", "no", "yes", "yes")
b2 <- c("no", "yes", "no")
list2 <- list(a2, b2)

list2

#[[1]]
#[1] "yes" "no"  "yes" "yes"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "no"  "yes" "no"
```

How can I index to only the columns in list1 that correspond to where list2 says "yes"?

In other words, can I index the columns of each matrix in list1 by the character values in list2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Map` the values together, and select the columns:

```
set.seed(1)
# run the rnorm/matrix code in the question to make it reproducible with this seed
Map(\(on,tw) on[, tw=="yes", drop=FALSE], list1, list2)
#[[1]]
#           [,1]      [,2]       [,3]
#[1,] -0.6264538 0.4874291 -0.3053884
#[2,]  0.1836433 0.7383247  1.5117812
#[3,] -0.8356286 0.5757814  0.3898432
#
#[[2]]
#            [,1]
#[1,] -0.01619026
#[2,]  0.94383621
#[3,]  0.82122120
#[4,]  0.59390132
```

Comment: `mapply` could also handle this task, but `Map` is perhaps more elegant.

Comment: @bzki - `Map` is `mapply(..., SIMPLIFY=FALSE)`, and since it's lists as input and lists as output, there's no point in trying to simplify.

Comment: @thelatemail thanks! This is great and answers the question. What I am ultimately after is how perform mathematical operations on only those indexed columns in the list while still keeping those columns in the original matrices in the list (i.e., still containing the "no" columns). How would I go about doing that?

Comment: @ZT_Geo - you'll need to overwrite the selection after processing it *inside* the function, and then return the whole object. E.g. `on[, tw=="yes"] <- on[, tw=="yes"] + 1; on` or similar.

Comment: @thelatemail - I am kind of new to the Map/ mapply function and can't get it to work but am probably just not fully understanding how to put it all together. What would the full code look like using the example from above? Thanks!

Comment: @ZT_Geo - like so: `Map(\(on,tw) {on[, tw=="yes"] <- on[, tw=="yes"] + 100; on}, list1, list2)` to add 100 to the selected columns.